# how to connect a linux server to remote mysql server permanently

Tags: mysql, linux

suppose my local linux server ip is 1:2:3:4, and the remote server on which i have to use mysql is 1:2:3:5. my local server also have mysql installed.
Now every query on my local linux server(1:2:3:4) should go to the remote mysql server(1:2:3:5) not the local mysql

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site about programming, you might get better help on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: it's called a router. Think Cisco, Amazon will sell ya one in the price range of $30 to $4k

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Proxy like MaxScale. They can send Query (i.e indert/update/delete)  to both servers.

Or you install a mysql replication. In this case the tables in Production are readonly.